# keycloak with 2 application and 2 realms

Tags: spring-boot, nginx, keycloak

I have `2 spring boot application` and `2 keycloak realms`. Each application uses own realm like application `1` configured for `realm A` and application `2` configured for `realm B`. But when i try to login into application `2` it automatically redirect me to `realm A`. Application `1` work as expected. For
`Realm A`  ldap is configured, and all stuff hosted behind nginx reverse proxy. No clue what wrong, all realms and applications properly configured.

Comment: For each application do you have front tend and back-end application ? If yes did you create two clients one for front end application and one for back-end application?

Comment: both application front-end each separated from another. And 2 separated realm with one client per realm

Comment: its something issue to declare the realm or client in config files then